# SendGrid Mail send is not working in my django rest-api view

Tags: django, django-views, smtp, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I tried to add the send mail using sendgrid in my django & react project, but it is not working.
My code in backend api view is like following:

```
import os
import json

from rest_framework.response import Response
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

def send_invitation(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
    TO_EMAILS = [('My Email Address', 'My fullname'), ]
    FROM_EMAIL = 'my another email address'
    TEMPLATE_ID = 'send-grid template id'

    message = Mail(
      from_email=FROM_EMAIL,
      to_emails=TO_EMAILS)

    message.dynamic_template_data = {
        'subject': 'SendGrid Development',
        'place': 'New York City',
        'event': 'Twilio Signal'
    }
    # message.add_filter('templates', 'enable', '1')
    message.template_id = TEMPLATE_ID
    
    try:
      sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
      response = sg.send(message)
      code, body, headers = response.status_code, response.body, response.headers
      print(f"Response code: {code}")
      print(f"Response headers: {headers}")
      print(f"Response body: {body}")
      print("Dynamic Messages Sent!")
      return Response({'message': 'Your Invitation is sent successfully!'})
    except Exception as e:
      print("Error {0}".format(e))
      return Response({'error': 'Your Invitation is failed to send!'})
```

I already add the SENDGRID_API_KEY in the .env file of my django backend, and installed the sendgrid using pipenv.
The error is like this; `Error HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Please let me know if the description is not enough.

Comment: Try to read the message in the response object.
Did your from_email is same as you config in the send grid dashboard against your API?
i highly recommend to try a python script first (provided in the docs of send grid) to ensure your there is no problem with your send grid configurations.
Cheers

Comment: from_email is the same with the config email in send grid api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the sender email authentication in the Sendgrid Web API settings.
I have solve this problem by add the sender email address into the sendgrid web api single authentication list.